# Is there any other way to retrieve data from a website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I think I have understood the way of working with ASP.Net MVC and I want to test my skills by creating a simple but useful (to myself) application that retrieves data from a certain web and stores it in a database i can handle.

I'm interested in spanish stocks markets and i'd like to retrieve the stock quotes that are posted to certain websites in order to use that data in my app.

The only way I know is HTML-based, is there any other way?

Comment: Mess around with json and c#

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to consider scraping 3rd party web sites as the very last resort. If possible, always try to use any web service or API they might provide.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What if they don't offer any API for that purpose?

Comment: If they don't offer any API it is very likely that they do not want to make their data available. You *could* still scrape the HTML of their pages but it is very likely that you will be violating their Terms of Use.

Comment: Find one that does. Like stackoverflow's rss and other formats

Comment: Ok. I'll try to find one that does. But one stupid question, which are these formats?